# Open Feign java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: MULTIPART_RELATED Error

Tags: java, file, upload, feign, openfeign

I want to upload a file with **Feign** like this :

```
    @FeignClient(name = "GDC", url = "${gdc.url}", configuration = ApiConfig.class)
    public interface GDCClient {
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/v1/document", consumes 
        ="multipart/form-data")
        Response saveDocument(@RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile fileSaveDocumentDTO, 
        @RequestPart(value = "document") SaveDocumentDTO saveDocumentDTO);
    }
```

But I have this error when I call saveDocument :

```
*java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: MULTIPART_RELATED
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringEncoder.isMultipartType(SpringEncoder.java:227) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar:2.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringEncoder.encode(SpringEncoder.java:102) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar:2.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.PageableSpringEncoder.encode(PageableSpringEncoder.java:101) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar:2.2.8.RELEASE]*
```

Someone can help me please ? :)

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

OpenFeign dependency class `org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringEncoder` contain constant `MULTIPART_RELATED` from `org.springframework.http.MediaType`. `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:2.2.8.RELEASE` and version above contain this `MULTIPART_RELATED` in SpringEncoder-class. I'm using  2.2.7.RELEASE

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the openfeign lib version is incompatible with the spring-web lib version and therefore cannot find the MediaType.MULTIPART_RELATED constant that should be in the MediaType class of the org.springframework.http package.

To solve the problem, use a version of the openfeign lib compatible with your spring-web lib.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade spring version at least 5.2.5

Comment: Add more details about the reason behind suggesting the upgrade.